# How can I change the Int value in Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make an unban command which sends the unbanned user a dm with the invite link where he was banned. Unfortunately this error always comes up:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
```

```
max_uses: int value should be less than or equal to 100.
```

I haven't been coding Discord bots for that long, so I don't know how to fix this error.
This is my code so far:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: 'Unban someone',
    async execute(message, args) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('You dont\' have permission to unban users.')
        let userID = args[0]
        message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans => {
            if (bans.size == 0) return
            let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id == userID)
            if (!bUser) return
            message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user)
        })
        
        let uses = args[0]
        let age = args[1]
        let invite = await message.channel.createInvite({
            maxAge: age * 60,
            maxUses: uses
        })

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('09aff')
        .setTitle('Unban')
        .setDescription(`Hey, ${userID}! You're unbanned again on ${message.guild.name}. Please stick to the server rules in future, so this doesn't happen again\n
        Click [here](${invite.code}) to rejoin ${message.guild.name}. Have fun!`)
        .setFooter('Zac was made by Zwiebelmilch#7904')
        .setTimestamp();

       await message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Comment: use `parseInt(uses)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Like that?: 
`maxUses: parseInt(uses)`
Edit: Worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `args[0]` value is either too big or its a string.

The option `maxUses` takes in an integer that is at most 100.
If you want to convert a string into a integer use the `parseInt()` function

Your code will then look like this:

```
let uses = parseInt(args[0])
let age = args[1]
let invite = await message.channel.createInvite({
   maxAge: age * 60,
   maxUses: uses
})
```

If this still doesn't work you should check what value you pass as the `args[0]` and if its below or equal to 100